# VisualStudio 2010 freezes anytime I delete a file

Tags: visual-studio, freeze

Anytime I delete a file in VisualStudio, the entire thing freezes and needs to be ended from TaskManager. I was hoping someone could help me troubleshoot this (or at least point me in the right direction to ask this question)

Facts:

- I am using Visual Studio 2010 Premium
- I have Windows XP
- I have no VS addins
- Moving a file, or Cut/Pasting it works fine. It's only when I delete that I freeze
- The file actually gets deleted, but my UI freezes and when I end program and restart it, the reference is still there and needs to be removed
- I can create a blank project, add a file, and delete the file to get it to crash on me
- CPU usage hangs at around 3-5% in Task Manager until I end the program

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS?

Comment: Are you running an antivirus software that could interfere with VS?

Have you tried reinstalling VS?

Are VS and .NET framework 4.0 up to date?

Comment: @Jason, @jball: The company uses Symantec Endpoint Protection v11, No I haven't tried reinstalling VS, and Yes the .Net framework is up to date. I was hoping to find a solution without reinstalling since the install takes quite a while, although if I can't I will give that a try

Comment: @Jason That was it. I've had so many problems with Symantec, I can't believe I didn't think to try that first! Thank you. If you post that as an Answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Try to empty your recycle bin as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183602/why-does-visual-studio-take-so-long-to-delete-a-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
The company uses Symantec Endpoint Protection v11, [...]
```

I don't know this antivirus software very well, but you could always try to temporarily disable it.

Comment: Thanks, Symantec was what was causing the problem. I added an exception for my project directory and the problem cleared up.

Comment: That one is infamous.  Had a nasty habit too of causing fatal execution engine errors.  A cure much worse than the problem.

Comment: Nevermind, I had a new folder name and had to add a new exception :)

Answer (score 0):

Hay Rachel,

First, the problem can be caused by the computer hardware: Not enough memory, CPU is too old, etc.

Check out the system requirements:

Visual Studio 2010 can be installed on the following operating systems:

•Windows XP (x86) with Service Pack 3 - all editions except Starter Edition
•Windows Vista (x86 & x64) with Service Pack 2 - all editions except Starter Edition
•Windows 7 (x86 & x64)
•Windows Server 2003 (x86 & x64) with Service Pack 2
•Windows Server 2003 R2 (x86 & x64)
•Windows Server 2008 (x86 & x64) with Service Pack 2
•Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64)
Supported Architectures:

•32-Bit (x86)
•64-Bit (x64)
Hardware Requirements
•Computer that has a 1.6GHz or faster processor
•1 GB (32 Bit) or 2 GB (64 Bit) RAM (Add 512 MB if running in a virtual machine)
•3GB of available hard disk space
•5400 RPM hard disk drive
•DirectX 9 capable video card running at 1024 x 768 or higher-resolution display
•DVD-ROM Drive

---

If you have what it needs :) then maybe reinstall can fix the problem..

Anyway, Have you tried to delete the file manualy from the directory
(C:\Users*Computer Name*\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects) and then deleting it from inside the Visual?

Hope I helped :)
Amihay