# Why does Visual Studio take so long to add a project or file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

It takes about 5 minutes to add a new `project` to a `solution` & roughly the same to add a `class` in **`Visual Studio`**.

The time is mainly waiting on the dialogue window to open.

I saw this solution for deleting files [Delete File VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183602/why-does-visual-studio-take-so-long-to-delete-a-file), is there a similar solution for what I am experiencing?

**Edit:**

- I experience this in `VS 05, 08, 10`
- The source control is `TFS` (solutions are brought locally, I assume this is implied)
- I have `Mcafee` software encryption
- My dev PC is a fast new business machine.
- No resharper
- Reflector installed
- SQL Prompt installed

I have debugged `Visual Studio`, and have found each time is tries to add an item it load all the **symbols** from the below directories which contain `dll`'s. I have tired deleting all the data in this folder but it comes back next time add something.

It appears the bulk of the time is spent loading the symbols...

[image]

Comment: Do you have any plugins running?

Comment: Run a second copy of VS and attach its debugger to the first, then pause while it's frozen and look at the stack trace.

Comment: Do you have a network drive?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Comment: @Jason This is a common problem. I know of about a dozen scenarios that can cause Visual Studio to run much slower than you'd expect, and for almost all of them I have reliable solutions. The question isn't too localized, it's actually not specific enough.

Comment: @280Z28: Any *every* one of your specific scenarios is too localized. Look at the solutions in your answer: it's "*highly* dependent" on *his* version of Visual Studio, the language *he* is using, *his* build configuration, *his* hardware, *his* configuration, *his* project's setup, *his* source control setup and many other things you left out, e.g. *his* tools (is he running R#, AVS), and on and on and on. You proved my point.

Comment: @280Z28 1) it is too localized, I think you mean the OP has not provided enough information 2) it should probably be on http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Jason that combination of items could just as easily refer to some specific open source project affecting a dozen companies and hundreds of developers.

Comment: The delete file link I gave worked like a charm, I thought there may have been something similar to this which is why I initially provided such constrained information.

Comment: @SLaks do you have an example of how to attached the debugger?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this is *highly* dependent on the version of Visual Studio you are using, the language you are using, and the particular build configuration your project is using. I would need to see all three, as well as your system hardware and software configuration to give you the precise cause.

However, based on the *absurdly long* time you listed (5 minutes), I predict that you are facing one of the following problems:

1. Your build configuration requires certain build steps be run the first time the project is loaded, and the build is taking a long time.
2. Your machine uses exceptionally out-of-date hardware, or has no available memory and is operating from a page file.
3. One or more of your projects is bound to source control, and the source control provider in Visual Studio and/or the server it's connecting to are running slowly. Try unplugging your computer from the network (or disabling your wireless card) and adding a project again. This will cause the source control connection to fail immediately so if adding a project becomes fast then you found the problem.

Comment: +1, another *potential* issue would be a misbehaving plugin. I agree though it is much more likely to be a source control provider.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a weird solution that somehow fixed my problem (same problem):

1. Open instance of VS in safe mode, then open project. Everything went fine here, except it asked if I wanted to unbind my source control. (Don't do this.)
2. Close that instance.
3. Open a normal instance and run normally.

No idea why this worked, but it did!

Comment: Lately, I've been having to do this every day. The method always works, but is a horrid work-around. I'm even planning to make a quick script to `open the solution in safemode, close it after 10s, reopen normally` quite the work-around. Need to find a better long-term solution!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any anti-virus software running?  My work laptop has McAfee and it tries to scan just about every files.  Next time it happens, check the task manager to see what hogging all the resources.

Comment: Antivirus is one of the situations that can cause Visual Studio to slow down, but it's extremely unlikely to cause it to slow down to this degree unless there's a legitimate bug in the software.

Comment: Yes McAfee, & it does software encryption I understand. This is in a work environment so no way to turn this off. I am not sure when or how the Anti Virus runs. @ChaiNavawongse

Comment: Thank you!  I've battling this for two years, but I added the folder to my virus scanner's exclusion and suddenly adding files was fast.